# Transfer number references to name references in word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a page of references with numbers.

`1. name of article
2. name of article
3. name of article`

I want to remove the numbers and have only the names. Plus, across the whole word file I have the references set as numbers as well ([1], [2]) and I want the references across the whole document to be changed to this format

`Balila et al. 2003; Marcus and Balila 2005; Fram 2007; Arazy and Fredman 2009`

for example.
The number references are linked across the whole document.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with a program called EndNote X7!
Just go to their website and download the 30-day trial

After installing the program, you will have a tab in word's ribbon with the program's name and you will be able to change to any format you need.

[EndNote X7 download](http://endnote.com/downloads/30-day-trial)